# PUT request to Cross Domain URL fails only in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

I want to do a PUT request across a different domain. But the script fails only in IE.

I figured out what the problem was, in IE if you look at Internet Options > Security tab > Custom level > Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains option was set to disable. The only way I was able to get my put request work is setting that option to Allow.

So my question: Is there a way I can get this working without enforcing end users to set the option?

There is XDomainRequest() which can be used for XDomain requests in IE but, this method doesn't support PUT.

Comment: are you whitelisting the PUT method using A.C.A.Methods?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: He's asking whether you've properly configured CORS support on the server, with an "Access-Control-Allow-Method" header. But the answer below is correct, XDomainRequest doesn't permit non-GET/POST verbs. You need IE10+ to use a PUT with XHR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE9 and older does not support PUT method in cross domain request. Only GET and POST.

Comment: So is there an alternative for that?

Comment: PUT method in CrossDomain support only IE10+. If you so need PUT method, you may use simple form with iframe.

Comment: Can you elaborate more and give an example probably?

Comment: Adi GuN: In form tag add attribute target="iframe_id". After submit event, server respons will push into this iframe without reload main page. But this way not so good. Better PUT giveway POST if you need support IE9-.

Comment: But I'm doing a PUT using XMLHttpRequest in javascript. There is no form involved.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest does not support PUT method in IE9- in crossDomain. And you can't change it.

Comment: You can't make cross-origin ajax requests in IE9 and older via XHR, you must use XDomainRequest.  What is XDomainRequest?  Well, it's just like XMLHttpRequest, with all of the useful stuff ripped out and a bunch of insane restrictions tacked on.  Oh, and it allows you to make  cross-origin ajax requests, but, again, there are some crazy rules you have to follow.  As @Mihail said, the PUT method is not supported by XDR.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like [Xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) or EasyXDM to get a CORS alternative using the Post Message hack.

I prefer to use Xdomain because it hijacks the native XMLHTTPRequest and provides a "drop-in" solution. EasyXDM forces you to use their API which means more conditional coding overhead, however, it supports IE6/IE7.

The main take away? Don't stop supporting CORS! Just make IE behave itself and opt-in to the future.